# TSQL getting the SUM of 2 separate counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that looks like below:

```
IF (@action = 'topDepartments')
                BEGIN
                    SELECT   TOP 50 E.[DepartmentDesc] AS department,
                                    COUNT(N.[nomineeQID]) AS totalNominations,
                                    COUNT(S.[subQID]) AS totalSubmissions
                    FROM     empTable AS E
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             empowermentSubmissions AS S
                             ON E.[qid] = S.[subQID]
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             empowermentSubmissions AS N
                             ON E.[qid] = N.[nomineeQID]
                    WHERE    N.[statusID] = 3
                             AND N.[locationID] = @locale
                    GROUP BY E.[DepartmentDesc]
                    ORDER BY totalSubmissions DESC
                    FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
                END
```

Everything is working great with it however I want to add both of the counts together as the grand total and then order it by the total.

I gave this a try but I kept getting the error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Is there a specific way this needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inside a query that is grouping, and you want to work with the aggregate values, treat the whole aggregate function as the column i.e. `COUNT(N.[nomineeQID])` is a column. So in your case just add the 2 aggregates together for the calculation.

```
IF (@action = 'topDepartments')
                BEGIN
                    SELECT   TOP 50 E.[DepartmentDesc] AS department,
                                    COUNT(N.[nomineeQID]) AS totalNominations,
                                    COUNT(S.[subQID]) AS totalSubmissions, 
                                    COUNT(N.[nomineeQID])
                                    + COUNT(S.[subQID]) AS ALLSubmissions
                    FROM     empTable AS E
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             empowermentSubmissions AS S
                             ON E.[qid] = S.[subQID]
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             empowermentSubmissions AS N
                             ON E.[qid] = N.[nomineeQID]
                    WHERE    N.[statusID] = 3
                             AND N.[locationID] = @locale
                    GROUP BY E.[DepartmentDesc]
                    ORDER BY totalSubmissions DESC
                    FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
                END
```

By the way, it might look "expensive" when we write queries this way, however the optimizers generally recognize that it can re-use a calculation, so it really isn't as bad as it may look.

Comment: Worked perfectly ; I appreciate it!